# Commas after date element when followed by a parenthetical

Tags: commas, parenthetical-commas, parentheses

In the sentence below, does a comma need to be placed after the parenthetical since a comma would normally come after 2020 in a full date?

Comma?
Review the document I gave you on May 2, 2020 (the May 2020 Document), for grammar and punctuation errors.

Or no comma?
Review the document I gave you on May 2, 2020 (the May 2020 Document) for grammar and punctuation errors.

Comment: Parenthetical information should have zero influence on the surrounding text. Write the sentence without the parenthetical information and punctuate it appropriately. Then add the parenthetical information back in again. Also, a comma does *not* normally come after the year in a full date. It's normally only put after the day. If there's a comma after the year, it's only because of the rest of the sentence.

Comment: I wonder if you're getting a bit confused by the possible use of commas to create a parenthetical insert. In your example this would be "...on May 2nd 2020, the May 2020 document, for grammar and..." As you presented the example I don't think that either comma is necessary.